# Unknown issue when calculating bouyancy in C++

Tags: c++, calculator

I'll cut to the chase: I made a program in C++ that calculates if a spherical object is bouyant or not for a class. However, after I (from what I thought) successfully made the program in Visual Studio 2013 when I submitted it where I need to (Pearon's terrible myProgrammingLab) I get the wrong output compared to Pearon's. (IE: Mine says it floats, they say it sinks, but don't show the calculations themselves.)

Here is my code:

```
// Bouyancy formula:
// Fb = V * y
// Where:
// Fb is the bouyant force
// V is the volume of the submerged object
// y is the specific weight of the fluid
// If Fb is greater than or equal to the weight of the object, then it will float, otherwise it will sink.

// Sphere volume formula:
// (4/3)pi(radius cubed)

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES // Used with math.h to provide access to M_PI (used in calculation of volume)
#include <math.h> // M_PI is the value of pie (3.14..)

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float sphere_radius, sphere_weight; // Stores the value of the Sphere's radius and weight in feet and pounds respectively.
    double water_weight = 62.4; // Value set to 62.4lb /cubic feet, this value is the "y" value in the above formula.
    double bouyant_force, volume; // Defines Fb and V in the Bouyancy formula listed above.

    cout << "Enter the radius of the sphere, in feet: ";
    cin >> sphere_radius;
    cout << "\nEnter the weight of the sphere, in pounds: ";
    cin >> sphere_weight;
    cout << endl;

    volume = ((4.0 / 3.0) * M_PI * (pow(sphere_radius, 3))); // Calculates the volume of the sphere
    bouyant_force = (volume * water_weight);
    if (bouyant_force >= sphere_weight)
    {
        cout << "The sphere will float." << endl;
    }
    else if (bouyant_force < sphere_weight)
    {
        cout << "The sphere will sink." << endl;
    }
    else { cout << "Something went terribly, terribly, wrong.. Oh dear.."; }

    char x; 
    cin >> x; //Waits for user to press a key before closing the program.
    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone please help me understand why this isn't correct or why it isn't being registered as correct? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Judging by your code, the error seems to be you directly comparing the weight you accept against the buoyant force. You should be multiplying the mass you accept(the pound is a unit of mass) by g in the unit system you are using. That seems to account for you getting that it flaots while the other side calculates that it sinks.

Comment: The site gave us a specific formula that didn't include gravity in the calculation. However, I'll try it, thanks

Edit: Same problem

Comment: @Scarecrow In physics, weight is not the same as mass. See e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weight). (Simplified: weight is mass scaled by gravity.)